# Flask app on OVH : ImportError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask, ovh

I'm using flask to build a project hosted on OVH. Unfortunately it doesnt work.

Here is my app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/test')
def test():
  return render_template('test.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

My requirement.txt :

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

My tree structure :

```
www
-templates
--- index.html
-requirement.txt
-my_py3_env
---pyvenv.cfg
---lib
-----python3.5
-------site-packages
---------flask
---bin
-app.py
-__pycache__
```

However, I get this output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/deposec/www/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Does anyone know why ?

EDIT : I have added the following .platform.app.yaml :

```
name: app
type: python:3.5

web:
    commands:
        start: "gunicorn -b $PORT project.wsgi:application"
    locations:
        "/":
            root: ""
            passthru: true
            allow: false
        "/static":
            root: "static/"
             allow: true

hooks:
    build: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install -e .
        pip install gunicorn

mounts:
    tmp:
        source: local
        source_path: tmp
    logs:
        source: local
        source_path: logs

disk: 512
```

However I still get No module named 'flask'... Do I also need a wsgi.py somewhere ?

Comment: Do you have a file `.platform.app.yaml` ? Reference: https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/web-paas/languages-python/#wsgi-based-configuration

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added a .platform.app.yaml in the www folder as explained on your reference. It doesnt work but it seems like I also need a wsgi.py somewhere ? Which one should I choose in this list ? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/index.html

Comment: What kind of service/server do you use at OVH ? Web Hosting ? VPS ? 
And how are you installing your `requirements` ? Do you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` somewhere ?

Comment: @Galiup, could you copy your `platform.app.yaml` file and the error that you get?

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard I have edited my post with the ```platform.app.yaml``` I have used. I still get the same error. However my launch script remains app.py, maybe it should be the yaml file ?

Comment: @PierreF I have run this exact same line of code in the terminal (connecting to the server using SSH). Should I include it in the launch script? My OVH service is a Cloud Web 1

Comment: Your build section looks suspicious. Is a typo or your `pip install -r requirements.txt` line is not aligned with the others?

Comment: It is a typo indeed

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are pointing ([here](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/web-paas/languages-python/#wsgi-based-configuration) is for the `OVHcloud Web PaaS powered by Platform.sh` offer, not the Cloud Web one. It's two different product.

This means your `.platform.app.yaml` is ignored on Cloud Web.

To install your Python dependencies in Cloud Web, the only available documentation is [here](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/cloud-web/installer-django-cms-cloud-web/), and seems to be only available in french.

You need to connect to your Cloud Web instance through SSH to run your `pip install` command.

It looks like:

```sh
# 1 - Connect to your Cloud Web through SSH
# You can find these infos in OVH Manager > Web > Your cloudweb > "FTP - SSH"
ssh <cloudweb_username>@sshcloud.cluster024.hosting.ovh.net -p <your port>

# 2 - Setup a Python virtualenv
pip3 install --user virtualenv
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.profile

# If "www" is your root dir, otherwise adjust it:
cd www/
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```